# iPhone app fatal error

Tags: iphone, fatal-error

Ok, I only made a minor change to a project of mine in Xcode (I just added a new .h, .m, and .xib file, they're very small), and now it won't run and gives me this message:

"fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe"

WTF? So I removed all the changes and tried to run it again and it STILL gives me the error, what's the deal?

Comment: Are you deploying to the simulator or to a device?

Comment: broken pipe means he is deploying to device

Answer (score 1):

Restart Xcode. If it still throws the error, disconnect your iOS device, reboot it, attach it again.

Comment: Arg! it's no good, it's broken. My Solution is to reinstall Xcode but I no longer have my Developer license (it expired...) is there anywhere to get the files again?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I get this error when I press run while my app is still working on the iphone. This may persist even if you restart xcode or your computer. What works for me is to hard restart the iphone. keep pressing powerbutton on iphone for 10 seconds untill it goes out and then press again, the error should go away.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I own no iPhone, I'm only running this in the simulator...